# trying to figure out 'if' condition in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
sayHi();
if (1) {
  function sayHi() {  console.log(1)  }
} else {
  function sayHi() {  console.log(2)  } 
}
</script>
```

In chrome->console, it shows:`2`

Question:

why `if(1)=false`?

Comment: This code is actually **ill-defined behavior** (and it is actually *syntactically invalid* per the official specification). Different browsers will result in different results; compare FF and IE. *Do not use FunctionDeclarations outside of a top-level Function/Program body!*

Comment: @Paul: Can you link to the relevant portion of the spec?

Comment: @Blender See the NOTE at http://es5.github.io/#x12 "Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support the use of FunctionDeclaration as a Statement. However there are significant and irreconcilable variations among the implementations in the semantics applied to such FunctionDeclarations. Because of these irreconcilable difference, *the use of a FunctionDeclaration as a Statement results in code that is not reliably portable among implementations*.." (This language was added in ES5, but the grammar is *invalid* in both 3rd and 5th editions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those function definitions aren't defined at the time of execution of that condition. Both functions are hoisted at the beginning, and the latter overwrites the former.

`if(1)` will always evaluate to true.

This hoisting is exactly what enables you to call the function apparently before it's defined. The following code will log `1`, but note that in that case you have to call it after the condition, otherwise you'll get an error `undefined is not a function`.

```
if (1) {
  var sayHi = function() {  console.log(1)  }
} else {
  var sayHi = function() {  console.log(2)  } 
}
sayHi();
```

Comment: The behavior (of the code in the question) is not well-defined under ECMAScript 3/5 and different browsers treat it differently. The grammar construct itself is actually forbidden. See the NOTE at http://es5.github.io/#x12